# Exactness of sequences preserved under resolution of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, short-exact-sequences

Let $X$ be a noetherian, affine, normal, isolated singularity and $\pi:\widetilde{X} \to X$ be a resolution of singularities. Suppose, we have an exact sequence (not necessarily short exact):
$$\mathcal{O}_X^{a_1} \xrightarrow{\phi_1} \mathcal{O}_X^{a_2} \xrightarrow{\phi_2} \mathcal{O}_X^{a_3}$$
with $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ defined by an $a_1 \times a_2$ and $a_2 \times a_3$-matrices respectively, with coefficients in $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X)$. Using the natural inclusion $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X) \subset \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}})$, the matrices corresponding to $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ define natural morphisms $\phi_1: \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{a_1} \to \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{a_2}$ and $\phi_2: \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{a_2} \to \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{a_3}$. Is the resulting complex 
$$\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{a_1} \xrightarrow{\phi_1} \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{a_2} \xrightarrow{\phi_2} \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{a_3}$$ also exact?

Comment: In general, it is not exact.